# Complete Intersection of a Veronese embedding as Five Quadrics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Consider the Veronese embedding given by the linear system $|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(2)|$, $\phi:\mathbb{P}^2\to \mathbb{P}^5$. In exercise IV.5 of Beauville, Complex Algebraic Surfaces, we prove that that the image is in fact given by all the symmetric matrices of rank 1, considering  points in $\mathbb{P}^5$ of the form:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
z_0 & z_1& z_2 \\
z_1 & z_3 &z_4\\
z_2 & z_4 & z_5 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$
However, the same exercise asks to prove that this image (hence the set of all these matrices with rank 1) is the complete intersection of 5 quadrics. Setting all the determinants of the $2\times 2$ minors zero, I could find nine relations, but by symmetry I could drop 3 of them, so I get:
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
z_0z_3-z_1^2=0 \\
 z_0z_4-z_1z_2=0\\
z_3z_5 -z_4^2  =0 \\
z_1z_4-z_2z_3=0\\
z_1z_5-z_2z_4=0 \\
z_0z_5 -z_2^2=0
\end{array} \right.$$
But they are 6, not 5. Is Beauville's exercise wrong or we can really realize that just as complete intersection of 5 quadrics?

Comment: It is not a complete intersection!

Answer (score 0):

The book does not say complete intersection! It simply says: "Deduce that $V$ is the intersection of $5$ quadrics in $\check{Q}$." Note that $V$ (the image of the above map) is $2$-dimensional, while $\check{Q} \cong \mathbb{P}^5$ is $5$-dimensional. So $V$ has codimension $3$. Beauville asks you to find $5$ equations, not $3$. So we are not showing that $V$ is a complete intersection.

All the $6$ equations you listed are in the ideal of the image $V$. They are minimal degree ($I(V)$ contains no linear forms). And they are linearly independent, in fact no two of them share any monomial. So it is not possible for any subset of $5$ of them to generate $I(V)$!

Instead, look for $5$ of the equations that **set-theoretically** define $V$, i.e., $5$ quadrics that generate $I(V)$ up to radical. Hint: pick one of the quadrics and show that a power of it lies in the ideal generated by the other $5$.

> For instance, $(z_0 z_4 - z_1 z_2)^2$ lies in the ideal generated by the other $5$ quadrics.

Comment: That is not right since you can also consider linear combinations of those equations. Actually, if you take a general 5-dimensional subspace in the 6-dimensional space of quadratic equations, the corresponding 5 quadrics generate $I(V)$.

Comment: Hm? The quadrics in $I$ are a $6$ dimensional space. They cannot be spanned by a $5$ dimensional subspace.

Comment: I did not say they span the space, what I say is that a general 5-dimensional subspace of quadrics generates the ideal.

Comment: How can they generate the ideal if they don’t even span the degree $2$ part? Are you talking about generating it up to saturation, ie, defining $V$ scheme-theoretically?

Comment: The morphism of sheaves $O^{\oplus 5} \to I_V(2)$ corresponding to this subspace is surjective, but the induced map on global sections is not (so the kernel of the map has non-trivial $H^1$).

Comment: You are talking about *ideal sheaves*. I am talking about *polynomial ideals*. We are both right, I think.

Comment: I agree, but the original question is about the sheaf of ideals.

Comment: Take a look at page 28 of these [lecture notes](https://web.stanford.edu/~aaronlan/assets/harris-undergrad-algebraic-geometry-notes.pdf).